# How to write Python script for linux-users with imports

Tags: python

I'm currently writing a Python Script that should be executable for users via terminal. I'll not be able to circumvent using imports like numpy, so I want to somehow wrap the installation of numpy within my python script - is it possible to  write something like a setup.py that checks for all modules if they are installed and installs the one's that are still needed?

Comment: "is it possible to..." Yes

Comment: "for linux-users" -- on a specific machine? If not, distributed *how*? You can reflect your dependencies in a RPM / Debian package / etc, and thus have the user's package management system make sure everything you need is installed; much better than trying to add installation logic yourself. (Similarly, if these are users on NixOS, you can create a `shell.nix` such that running `nix-shell` in your program's directory puts all the dependencies into the user's environment... etc, etc).

Comment: Working *with* OS-level software-installation facilities instead of fighting against them also makes it easier for folks trying to generate reports on what software is installed, or ensure that they only install bits from an audited package source, or ensure that they can create a new machine with the exact same tooling preinstalled, etc.

Comment: I believe you are looking for either packaging your software for distribution or perhaps a thing called "virtual environment".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be possible via pip support

#### Worst Case Scenario

**Python 3.x**

```
import pip
try:
    import numpy as np
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    pip.main(["install", "numpy", "--user"])
```

**Python 2.x**

```
import pip
try:
    import numpy as np
except ImportError:
    pip.main(["install", "numpy", "--user"])
```

#### Using Setup.py [Recommended][Convinient]

If you want to simplify your `setup.py` writing task, you can use [morphine](https://github.com/tbhaxor/morphine/). It is a GUI Framework to simplify the work of creating `python setup files`

Comment: Please don't actually do this. As an end-user, if I found programs I ran silently installing new software, I would be very annoyed.

Comment: This wont install package silently

Comment: "Silently" meaning, in this context, "without affirmative assent".

Comment: @CharlesDuffy oh my bad :v

Comment: I gave another option, Using Setup.py